# Convolution of an Image in python

Tags: python, image, convolution

I run the following script
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import signal as sg

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sg

def np_from_img(fname):
return np.asarray(Image.open(fname), dtype=np.float32)

def save_as_img(ar, fname):
Image.fromarray(ar.round().astype(np.uint8)).save(fname)

def norm(ar):
return 255.*np.absolute(ar)/np.max(ar)

img="src/img.png"
save_as_img(norm(sg.convolve(img, [[1.],[-1.]])), 'src/portal-h.png')
```

I am having the following error:
ValueError: in1 and in2 should have the same dimensionality

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your input is an RBG image that is converted to a 3D array instead of a 2D one.

Try replacing `img` with `img.mean(axis=-1)`.

Comment: In fact it is a gray scale one.

Comment: Can you `assert len(ar.shape) == 2`? If this is True, maybe the shape of the kernel may trigger the error (the fact that is effectively a 1D convolution...)

Comment: Actually `sg.convolve(np.random.rand(10, 10), [[1], [-1]])` works so your error seems to be related to `img` dimensionality.